# Convergence in distribution of sum of two variables conditional on one variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, conditional-probability

Let us consider the statistic
$$U_n  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\epsilon_{i, n}}{\sigma_{i,n}} + f(\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}),$$
where, conditional on $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$, $\epsilon_{i, n} \overset{iid}{\sim}$ some distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2_{i, n}$ and $f$ is a continuous function. The variables $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$ are not independent.

I have an approximation of the asymptotic distribution of $f(\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})$. I know the quantiles. But I am not sure that this is important for my question.

My purpose is to approximate the quantile of $U_n$ conditional on $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$. This is how I proceed, but I am not sure whether it is theoretically correct. If not, how to adjust the result?

- Conditional on $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$, I argued that  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\epsilon_{i, n}}{\sigma_{i,n}}$ is asymptotically normally distributed. The intuition is that if the treat $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$ as nonstochastic, the Lyapunov central limit theorem can be used if $$\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}\lvert\epsilon_{i,n}\rvert^{2 + \delta}}{\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_{i,n}^2} = o_p(1).$$
  Can the conditional asymptotic distribution be stated in this way?
- If the preceding point is correct, can I say that
  $\mathbb{P}(U_n < x|\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})$ has the same limit as $\mathbb{P}(\zeta < x - f(\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})|\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})$, where $\zeta\sim N(0, 1)$?

What will be the implication of the result? I can finally estimate the unconditional distribution function as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(\zeta < x - f(\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})|\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n})).$$

I can estimate the above quantity by replacing the expectation by an empirical mean if I have realizations (simulations) of $\sigma_{1, n},\dots,\sigma_{n, n}$.

Comment: What does it mean for $X_n$ to converge in distribution to some random variable $V$ conditional on $Y_n$? Does $V$ depend on $Y_n$? Can you give an equation to show what you mean? Something like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X_n\leq x|Y_n=y]= P[V\leq x]$  for all $x$ at which the CDF of $V$ is continuous? Why does the left-hand-side of my equation depend on $y$ but the right-hand-side does not?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my post (I gave an example).

Comment: Your example is atypical. What you have is a sequence of random measures  $\mu_n(\omega,\cdot)$ which converge to the $\textbf{same}$ measure for every $\omega$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @Andrew Yes I can start this this. but it may not converge to the same measure. But for every $\omega$, I simplified the example. Understanding this one can help me.

Comment: This is problematic because, ignoring any precise meanings to the problem, if $X_n+Y_n$ conditional on $Y_n$ were to have a limiting distribution, the distribution would be different for each $\omega$.

Comment: And moreover, in your example, the measure conditional on $Y_n$ is $\mathcal N(\sigma_n^2,1)$, so there cannot be a convergence to anything without some more assumptions. Also, by the way in your example $X_n\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ even unconditionally

Comment: @andrew the normal distribution for U is for simplicity. So having $X_n$ normal is not something useful here.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean by "conditional convergence in distribution" is not useful because it immediately implies unconditional convergence in distribution. Suppose for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[X_n\leq x|Y \in A] = P[V\leq x]$ for all points $x$ at which the CDF of $V$ is continouous. Take $A =\mathbb{R}$ and we see the event $\{Y\in \mathbb{R}\} = \Omega$ so $P[X_n\leq x|Y\in \mathbb{R}] = P[X_n\leq x]$.

Comment: In another direction, you may want to use a test case $V\sim N(0,1)$. If $X_n$ converges to $V$ in distribution, then it would also converge to $-V$ in distribution. Define $X_n=V$ and $Y_n=-V$ for all $n$. Then $X_n+Y_n=0$, $V+Y_n=0$,$-V+Y_n=-2V$.

Comment: @Michael, Thank you for your reply. I now added details. The new post is very close to what I am looking for. I think I cannot take $A = R$, because I can only condition on a specific value.

Comment: In your new question, if $\{\epsilon_{i,n}\}_{i=1}^n$ are conditionally i.i.d. given the $\sigma_{i,n}^2$ values, and their variances are also $\sigma_{i,n}^2$, then   the variances must all be the same, so $\sigma_{i,n}^2=\sigma_{1,n}^2$ for all $i \in\{1, ...,n\}$. Perhaps you just meant they are conditionally independent, but not necessarily identically distributed.

Comment: Assuming you just meant independence (but not iid), define $G_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\epsilon_{i,n}}{\sigma_{i,n}}$, then indeed $$P[U_n\leq x] = E[P[G_n\leq x - f(\sigma_{1,n},...,\sigma_{n,n})|(\sigma_{1,n},...,\sigma_{n,n})]]$$ One problem is that even if $G_n$ goes to a Gaussian distribution, its convergence may be slower at the tails and so we worry about the size of $f(\sigma_{1,n},...,\sigma_{n,n})$ relative to the speed at which $G_n$ converges to a Gaussian. I'm also not familiar enough with the CLT for non-iid variables to know what other problems may arise.